# Stopping service called using alarm manager after the alarm time

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager

I need help to stop a service automatically after the time specified in alarm Manger is expired. Below is the code:

```
Intent c = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallService.class);                        
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, c, 0);        
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 9*10000, pintent);
```

Even after the time specified is expired the service keeps running in background, how can I stop the service to stop immediately after the time is expired?

Comment: I had an initial thought of using Timertask when the service is started to count down the the time and execute stopself on service at the exact moment. Is it a correct approach or very resource consuming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Timertask to cancel the intent after specified time:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
    TimerTask welcome = new TimerTask(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
         //Stopped the service
        }
    };
    t.schedule(welcome, 300, 30000);
```

Below webpage has details on how to use timertask
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/413950/TimerTask-in-Android

Answer (score 0):

call alarm.cancel(pintent);
try this after a sleep of specified time or  just write it down below alarm.set();
most probably it will be called only after the time expires .If that doesn't fulfill the purpose than use thread.sleep for the specified time  and then call
alarm.cancel(pintent);